# What is the correct way to change selection of a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I am having a problem to change a selected item in a drop-down.

The way I use is (a property in the code behind which sets the new selection):

```
public char Candy
{
set
    {

        var newSelection = ddlCandy.Items.FindByValue(value.ToString());
        ddlCandy.ClearSelection();
        newSelection.Selected = true;

    }
}
```

Is this a recommended and proper way?

Comment: Note: If you databind the DropDownList afterwards, the selection gets cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safe way is fist Find the given item from DropDownList and set it as SelectedValue

```
ListItem oListItem = DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue("yourValue");
if(oListItem != null)
{
 DropDownList1.SelectedValue = oListItem.Value;
}
```

if you directly assign SelectedValue it may through an exception if it is not exist in the list like bellow.

> 'DropDownList' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does
>   not exist in the list of items.

Answer (score 2):

recommended approach is to simply assign the `SelectedValue` property with the `Value` you have and the `DropDownList` control will find and select the proper item for you, if any.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to use `SelectedValue`:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "Foo";
```